# How to access a row in a pandas dataframe with custom index labels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, tf-idf

I've created a pandas dataframe to hold the data like so:

```
TF_IDF = pd.DataFrame(index = vocab)
TF_IDF['0'] = 0
```

where `vocab` is an array of strings, so the index label of each column is the corresponding string

so when I print it, it looks like this:

```
           0
life       0
math       0
student    0
experi     0
control    0
...       ..
slave      0
linga      0
31-32      0
democrat   0
unsustain  0
```

How would I access a row at a given index by using a string?

for example, if I have the string "math" how would one access the value using the index label "math"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) rather than chained indexing (as in your answer) as it's more efficient, and chained indexing can sometimes raise a `SettingWithCopy` warning (read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)).

To use .loc, you would call it like below:

```
df.loc[row_index(es), col_names]
```

Which would be the below in your example:

```
TF_IDF.loc['life', '0']
```

returns:

```
0
```

Answer (score 0):

`TF_IDF['0']['life']` will get you there

Instead of removing the question, I'll leave it up, just in case someone else also cant find the answer anywhere else online